# ¿Como dejar por defecto que hibernate no interfiera con el Id de tipo serial de postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, spring-mvc

Tengo un campo `ID` en **PostgreSQL** de tipo `serial`, para que sea autoincremental. Pero cuando realizo el mapeo con Hibernate el `.xml` de la tabla se guarda así:

```
`<class name="Model.Persona" table="persona" schema="public" optimistic-lock="version">
    <id name="id" type="int">
        <column name="id" />
        <generator class="assigned" />
    </id></class>`
```

Esto hace que cuando deseo enviar un registro a la base de datos no toma en cuenta el autoincrementable de la base de datos y crea conflicto.

Comment: favor de no colocarle SOLUCIONADO a tu pregunta, eso no es válido ni bien visto aqui, debes aceptar la respuesta que te solucionó el problema

Comment: Habia leido en unos terminos que me mandaron hace poco que si una respuesta ya estaba solucionada debia escribirlo entre corchetes en el título. Gracias por el aviso.

Comment: no, eso no aplica en SO en español

Comment: Bueno, lo lamento, aunque por otro lado, ¿Podrias retirar el voto negativo?, la respuesta de verdad que si ayuda a quienes tienen problemas con Spring MVC y me tomo su tiempo el darle solución ya que no era un tema trivial.

Comment: yo no te puse el -1 pero si te puedo dar un +1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para quien tenga un problema similar, he aquí a la solución a la cual he llegado:

```
<class name="Model.Persona" table="persona" schema="public" optimistic-lock="version"> 
      <id name="id" type="int">
      <column name="id" />
      <generator class="sequence">
          <param name="sequence">persona_id_seq</param>
      </generator>
</id>
```

Consiste en definir la clase de generación "assigned" a "sequence", una vez que lo definan como secuencia ingresan como parámetro el nombre de la secuencia que genera `PostgreSql` (El nombre es muy intuitivo, nombreDeLaTabla_campo(id)_seq).

De esta forma `Hibernate` dejara todo el trabajo de generación de la Id a la base de datos. Espero sea de ayuda a alguien mas. Un saludo.